# Optimally serving large background images across multiple resolutions

Tags: css, image, performance, media-queries, background-image

I have a very large hero image, set as a background-image, that takes up the entire initial viewport size. I want to serve up multiple sizes based on device resolution for improved speed.

Media queries seem like the best approach, but I have some questions about implementing them:

- Would it be better to use the `width` feature or `device-width` feature? I'm thinking the latter, because the width can change if a user resizes their browser, which could trigger a new background-image to load. With `device-width`, I can detect the largest possible screen size and load an image whose dimensions can look good if the user resizes their browser to full size.
- How do you accommodate for pixel density? I need to make the images twice as big, or in some cases, three times as big, so they render properly on devices with large pixel density. So I can't really cut down the image size that much when I have to account for potentially high pixel density. I could make media queries targeting specific pixel densities and device-widths together, but that's seems like a complicated and suboptimal solution.

I'd love to hear some solutions people have found for this.

Comment: Here is a couple of articles worth reading, http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-images-in-practice and https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: Good read here, https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/